# Word meaning a small but significant risk

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word referring to a risk which has low probability but high impact? I'm thinking of something that is dangerous but easily overlooked.

Sample sentence: The emerging field of AI ethics has not yet addressed the ___ risk of creation of a sentient AI.

Comment: Note that if you're using a [Risk Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_matrix), a rare but catastrophic hazard is still "high risk." In fact, calling it a "rare, catastrophic risk" may be ideal since you'll be referring directly to risk matrices.

Comment: You could say it's a [***non-negligible** risk,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22non-negligible+risk%22) same as thousands of other writers.

Comment: What 'risk'?  I thought that was the 'goal'! ;)

Comment: @FumbleFingers 'non-negligible' is mealy -mouthed. Many things that matter but not really all that  much are non-negligible.

Comment: If it is important to separate the probability and the magnitude that the harm would have (if it were to occur), then no single word will do; one has to spell out in several words what one has in mind. The single-word terms that are used to characterise risk (*high, great, small, significant, negligible,* etc.) all jumble together the two dimensions of risk. That's why, incidentally, the title of this question does not capture what was intended (*small* is not specific to the probability; *significant* is not specific to the magnitude of the possible harm).

Comment: @JeremyC: Not sure what you mean by that. I understand *meal-mouthed* as meaning *euphemistic or evasive* (coming from someone who's afraid to speak plainly). But we usually speak of a ***non-negligible risk*** in contexts such as the (remote) possibility of Earth being "sterilised" by a large comet impact. Such things, ***if they were to happen***, would usually be considered catastrophic - hardly "things that matter but not really all that much." They *would* matter an awful lot if they actually happened - it's just that they're not *likely*, not that they "don't matter".

Answer (score 1):

It's a **Black swan**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_swan_theory
https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/blackswan.asp

A black swan is an unexpected event, difficult to predict and with a high impact.

Answer (score 0):

I've sometimes heard these described as **landmines**, things that are not easily spotted but blow up in a big way once they're tripped over.

Answer (score -1):

You need to be more precise about what you mean by "high impact". If you mean an impact that would undermine human life as we know it, that is one thing; if you mean an open-ended bet that would leave my family destitute if I lost, that is another. The first affects all humanity, the latter just my family.

There is also a problem with your example sentence because it might not be obvious why sentient AI presents a high impact risk. If you believe that it is obvious that it does then you can simply use some such word as 'catastrophic'.